# calendar test passes when using AndroidJunit4 only

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit4

I have a weird case. I am running a local test and using the Calendar class within that test.

when annotating the test class with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` the test passes, otherwise, the test fails.

the test code doesn't include any Android environment library

here is my class

```
class MyDateUtils(private val calendar: Calendar) {

    fun getDates(): Long{
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY)
        return calendar.timeInMillis
    }
}
```

and here is the test case, this one passes

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyDateUtilsTest {

    private lateinit var calendar: Calendar
    private lateinit var dateUtils: MyDateUtils

    @Before
    fun init() {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = 1592422768000
        dateUtils = MyDateUtils(calendar)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when get dates is called with wednesday day should return sunday of the same week`() {
        val expected = 1592163568000

        val actual = dateUtils.getDates()

        assertEquals(expected, actual)

    }
}
```

now when I remove `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` the test fails with this error message `java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected :1592163568000 Actual   :1592768368000`

P.S the expected behavior is that the `getDates()` method return Sunday within the same week. but **without** `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` it return the following Sunday (The next week).

Comment: I'd guess it's a locale issue somewhere, due to running the test on a computer instead of a device. After you set the current time, if you make a call to ``getTimeInMillis`` (before you set the day) does that make it consistent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I am not sure what exactly you want me to try. can you clarify?

Comment: This might be something to do with the default locale that might be changed when you run with AndroidJUnit4. I wonder if the first day of the week is different depending on whether you are running with that. 1. You could write some debug statements to answer this. 2. Can you post the code that calculates the date? (what calculates the value returned by `getDates()`).

Comment: Hi, @PedroLoureiro . I think you are right. it has to do with the locale. I've tried debugging in both cases and checking for ```val first = calendar.firstDayOfWeek``` and I found out that the results are different, so in my test I set the locale like this ```locale = Locale("US")
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale)``` and is passed. consider writing this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. thanks

Comment: I'm saying does ``calendar.timeInMillis = 1592422768000; calendar.getTimeInMillis(); dateUtils = MyDateUtils(calendar)`` make it work? ``Calendar``s are created with the current time (which depends on locale), and when you set ``timeInMillis`` it doesn't actually get recalculated until you call a ``get`` method. So it's possible when you set the time, and then the day, the pending time change gets overwritten/ignored. Calling a ``get`` method after setting the time would lock it in. ``Calendars`` are weird and complicated

Comment: but you fixed it with the locale anyway, so don't worry about it!

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for commenting. I call ```dateUtils.getDates()``` before I assert. so it should match the expected date. anyway I solved it thanks to @Pedro comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something to do with the default locale that might be changed when you run with AndroidJUnit4.

With different locales the first day of the week is different and that could make the tests fail or pass depending on the runner.